# Error when resolving API response in Svelte template

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm new to Svelte. Using Typescript, I'm trying to have/test a basic component displaying an API response:

```
<script lang="ts">

    import axios from 'axios';
    import { env } from "$env/dynamic/public";
    import type { Submission } from '../models/submission';

    export const getSubmission = async (uuid: string): Promise<Submission> => {
        const { data, status } = await axios.get<Submission>(env.PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + '/submissions/' + uuid);
        if (status === 200) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            return data;
        } else {
            throw new Error('API response error');
        }
    };

    const submissionUuid = '90f5844c-b8f4-4ce1-90af-5d200d4770b5';

</script>

<div>

    {#await getSubmission(submissionUuid)}
        <h1>loading...</h1>
    {:then submission}
        <p>the submission status is {submission.status}</p>
    {:catch error}
        error displaying submission
    {/await}

</div>
```

Unfortunately, I always get an error when resolving the promise ("error displaying submission" displayed on the web page), although the API response is going fine and correctly logged by the `console.log` in the API call function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This should work I think. Try logging the `error` you get in the `:catch` block, to see if you get the `'API response error'` or something else.
For that, you can use the [@debug](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/debug) tag.

```html
    {:catch error}
        {@debug error}
        error displaying submission
    {/await}
```

Comment: Unfortunately and strangely it didn't display anything. Note that no error is catch in the API fetching function (data is logged correctly in the terminal), so I believe it's a promise resolution issue / type issue.